# Cisco IOS: access-list logging rate-limited or missed packets

Tags: cisco, logging, access-control-list, ios

How do we fix these errors?

```
2629753: Dec 29 09:03:56.521 EST: %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGRL: access-list logging rate-limited or missed 2 packets
```

This is a Cisco 871 router with BVI and access lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message means that an ACL (with, presumably, logging enabled) is generating syslog messages faster than the router is willing to send them off. You'll have to increase the rate-limit, use the `logging rate-limit` command to do this (you'll probably want to use the `ip access-list logging interval` command as well).

Then, tweak the rate-limit and interval until lowering them starts generating the rate-limit messages and up them a bit. The exact values will depend on your traffic profile and you may find that you'll have to accept these during traffic peaks.

Comment: I looked at `(config)#logging rate-limit ?` and it says `<1-10000>  Messages per second` so that is very clear.. but what about `ip access-list logging interval`? Is it supposed to be the same as `rate-limit`?

Comment: I believe that is a minimum time between ACL log messages. Basically, you need to allow more log messages to be generated. But, the 871 is not the fastest hardware platform around and I don't know if "have ACL" directly implies "process-switched" or not. You may actually be on the limit of what your hardware can do.

Comment: OK.. I looked again it says `Access list logging interval (milliseconds)`.. It seems like I would have already checked that the first time :P . I looked at `show run | include ...` and it seems I must be using default values for both. I set the ACL `interval` to 0 and will play around with the `rate-limit` option to see if it works the way I think it does. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to set the level of logging you are doing

There are 7 levels, I'm not sure which one you need, but I think this would be a good place to start.

0—emergencies
1—alerts
2—critical
3—errors
4—warnings
5—notification
6—informational
7—debugging

Comment: I edited my question. I was not just talking about hiding the messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not immediately sure if this is a central logging server, but I'm inclined to think so. You're either seeing dropped packets, or messages are being generated to fast. Options are to fix your network congestion / reliability, or find a way to reduce the items being logged.

Comment: This is a Cisco 871 router with BVI and access lists. (edited my question)